# TortoiseGit stops connecting after a seemingly random amount of time

Tags: windows-7, ssh, git

I use TortoiseGit to connect to a private remote git server, but after an indeterminate amount of time (possibly longer than 6 hours?), trying to connect results in a bad file number error. I've tried this from multiple different networks, though it hasn't yet failed while connecting to it over lan. I'm not terribly experienced with git.

The error:
git.exe pull -v --progress      "origin"
ssh: connect to host [IP redacted] port 22: Bad file number

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1)

Comment: What's the error exactly?